# Travar o scroll do body até uma certa altura

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

Boa tarde pessoal, meu problema é o seguinte:

Quando abro o menu mobile do meu site, a altura do scroll permanece gigante (do tamanho total da página).
E eu não posso adicionar posição 'fixed' no body pois o meu menu tem uma altura maior do que 100vh (o menu possui scroll Y).

O que eu preciso é o seguinte: quando abrir o menu, limitar o scroll do body somente até o final da div do menu. Dessa maneira eu poderia manter o scroll para visualizar todo o menu, mas não ficaria com um scroll gigante à toa.

1. -> quando abre o menu, adiciona a classe "open" - OK
2. -> com o menu aberto, setar a altura do body igual à altura total do menu - OK
3. -> limitar o scroll até o final da altura do menu (para não ficar com um scroll gigante) - pendente

Estou fazendo com jquery

meu site: www.barradatijuca.com.br

Procurei muito sobre uma solução para meu problema e não achei...
Tentei até usar o scrolltofixed plugin, mas não funcionou...
Obrigado pela atenção

Comment: Se você adicionar um `position: fixed` no menu, fazer com  que ele ocupe 100% da largura e altura da tela e adicionar um overflow:hidden nele o menu vai ocupar 100% da tela, e o conteúdo dentro dele vai ficar "rolavel". Nesse caso ele iria abrir sobrepondo body.

Comment: Não funcionou amigo, se eu colocar o menu com position fixed, ele não vai rolar pra baixo e alguns itens não vão aparecer.
Obrigado de qualquer forma.

Comment: Opá! Eu me confundi, na verdade o menu deve receber um `overflow: auto`, ai o conteúdo que não aparece vai ter scroll.

Comment: Por que você não faz um `min-height:296px;` no seu `.menu-mobile.open{}` e tira o  `height: 100%`. É uma solução mais funcional para o seu problema, acredito.

Comment: Para remover o scroll é so usar media queries: `@media (max-height:680px)  { body { overflow-y: hidden; } }`. Pior do que remover o scroll até o inferno do seu menu, é esconder o conteúdo do usuário, eu não recomendo isso.

Comment: Srs. agradeço a tentativa, mas nenhum método funcionou para resolver meu problema.
@IvanFerrer mesmo retirando o 100% e colocando min-height no menu, o scroll do body continua.

Comment: A "n" formas de fazer isso @HugoDeveza, o problema é que você não publicou nada de código na pergunta, então fica difícil publicar uma resposta baseado somente no endereço do site que você está produzindo. Eu vou até publicar uma resposta que poderia ser aplicada ao seu sistema, mas não creio que você vá saber utilizar.

Answer (score 1):

Uma maneira de resolver o problema é removendo o `scroll` da página ou elemento desejado, até que a altura do rolamento atinja a marca, entretanto, você irá precisar informar que esta regra só funciona para a versão mobile (já que se trata de uma versão responsiva), para que não ocorra o problema quando estiver em tela cheia no PC.

```
$(function() {
 var mobile = isMobile(), /* aqui você retornaria "true"
                             através de algum método que
                             define quando for mobile
                             ou a medida que você considera 
                             aceitável */
     altura_limite = 825; 
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= altura_limite && mobile == true) {
            $('body').css('overflow':'hidden');
        } else {
            $('body').css('overflow':'auto');
        }
    });
});
```

Uma outra sugestão é criar uma classe no elemento:

```
body.hide-scroll {
  overflow:hidden
}
```

Ao invés de setar o `.css()`, toda vez que ele atingisse o limite do rolamento da página.

```
   $(function() {
     var mobile = true, altura_limite = 825; 
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() >= altura_limite && mobile == true) {
                $('body').addClass('hide-scroll');
            } else {
                $('body').removeClass('hide-scroll');
            }
        });
    });
```

Aqui um exemplo de método para versões mobile:

```
function isMobile() { 
 if (typeof window.orientation !== 'undefined') {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```